# MYSQL put users with no profile picture at the bottom, but everyone else still by the other ORDER properties

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So what I want to to is put users that don't have a profile picture at the VERY VERY bottom of the page.

but if they do have a picture, then it skips them, and adds them to the following rules

```
SELECT users.id as id, users.username as username,    
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(userprofiles.birthdate)), '%Y')+0 AS age,   
       userprofiles.defaultpictureid as picture, city.City 
  FROM users, 
       userprofiles, 
       Cities as city 
 WHERE users.id = userprofiles.userid 
   AND city.CityId = userprofiles.city 
   AND userprofiles.online = '1' 
   AND userprofiles.country = ".$this->country." 
   AND userprofiles.state = ".$this->state." 
ORDER BY if (userprofiles.city = ".$this->city.",0,1) AND userprofiles.membertype DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misreading the question since you already have the concept of an `IF` inside the `order by` but this should work assuming when defaultpictureid is null when the user doesn't have a picture

```
....
ORDER BY
    if( userprofiles.defaultpictureid is null,1,0),
    if (userprofiles.city = ".$this->city.",0,1)  
....
```

Some DBs don't have an IF statement like this. In ones that don't they usually have the case (mysql has both)

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN userprofiles.defaultpictureid is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
```

this is also useful when you have more values than just 1 and 0 and you don't want to do nested ifs

Comment: I think the use of `AND` within the ORDER BY may be an issue, too.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, MySQL should allow you to do something like this: `ORDER BY userprofiles.defaultpictureid is null, ... (other criteria)`.